# Why my texture coordinates are inverted each time I call my glsl shader in p5js?

Tags: glsl, processing, shader, p5.js

I am trying to use a glsl shader with p5js to create a simulation like the game of life. To do that I want to create a shader which will take a texture as uniform and which will draw a new texture based on this previous texture. In a next iteration this new texture will be used as uniform and that should allow me create a simulation following the idea exposed [here](https://www.alanzucconi.com/2016/03/02/shaders-for-simulations/). I am experienced with p5.js but I'm completely new to shader programming so I'm probably missing something.

For now my code is as straightforward as possible:

- In the `preload()` function, I create a texture using the `createImage()` function and setup some pixels to be white and the others to be black.
- In the `setup()` function I use this texture to run the shader a first time to create a new texture. I also set a timer to run the shader at regular intervals and draw the result in a buffer.
- In the `draw()` function I draw the buffer in the canvas.
- To keep things simple I keep the canvas and the texture the same size.

**My issue is that at some point the `y` coordinates in my code seems to get inverted and I don't understand why.** My understanding is that my code should show a still image but each time I run the shader the image is inverted. Here is what I mean:

[image]

I am not sure if my issue comes from how I use glsl or how I use p5 or a mix of both. Can someone explain to me where this weird `y` inversion comes from?

Here is my minimal reproducible example (which is also in the p5 editor [here](https://editor.p5js.org/statox/sketches/yZkmrOhW7)):

The sketch file:

```
const sketch = (p5) => {
    const D = 100;
    let initialTexture;

    p5.preload = () => {
        // Create the initial image
        initialTexture = p5.createImage(D, D);
        initialTexture.loadPixels();
        for (let i = 0; i < initialTexture.width; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < initialTexture.height; j++) {
                const alive = i === j || i === 10 || j === 40;
                const color = p5.color(250, 250, 250, alive ? 250 : 0);
                initialTexture.set(i, j, color);
            }
        }
        initialTexture.updatePixels();

        // Initialize the shader
        shader = p5.loadShader('uniform.vert', 'test.frag');
    };

    p5.setup = () => {
        const canvas = p5.createCanvas(D, D, p5.WEBGL);
        canvas.parent('canvasDiv');

        // Create the buffer the shader will draw on
        graphics = p5.createGraphics(D, D, p5.WEBGL);
        graphics.shader(shader);

        /*
         * Initial step to setup the initial texture
         */
        // Used to normalize the frag coordinates
        shader.setUniform('u_resolution', [p5.width, p5.height]);
        // First state of the simulation
        shader.setUniform('u_texture', initialTexture);
        graphics.rect(0, 0, p5.width, p5.height);

        // Call the shader each time interval
        setInterval(updateSimulation, 1009);
    };
  
    const updateSimulation = () => {
        // Use the previous state as a texture
        shader.setUniform('u_texture', graphics);
        graphics.rect(0, 0, p5.width, p5.height);
    };

    p5.draw = () => {
        p5.background(0);
        // Use the buffer on the canvas
        p5.image(graphics, -p5.width / 2, -p5.height / 2);
    };
};

new p5(sketch);
```

The fragment shader which for now only takes the color of the texture and reuses it (I tried using `st` instead of `uv` to no avail):

```
precision highp float;

uniform vec2 u_resolution;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;

// grab texcoords from vert shader
varying vec2 vTexCoord;

void main() {
    // Normalize the position between 0 and 1
    vec2 st = gl_FragCoord.xy/u_resolution.xy; 
    // Get the texture coordinate from the vertex shader
    vec2 uv = vTexCoord;
    // Get the color at the texture coordinate
    vec4 c = texture2D(u_texture, uv);
    // Reuse the same color
    gl_FragColor = c;
}
```

And the vertex shader which I took from [an example](https://github.com/aferriss/p5jsShaderExamples) and does nothing excepted passing the coordinates:

```
/*
 * vert file and comments from adam ferriss https://github.com/aferriss/p5jsShaderExamples with additional comments from Louise Lessel
*/ 

precision highp float;

// This “vec3 aPosition” is a built in shader functionality. You must keep that naming.
// It automatically gets the position of every vertex on your canvas
attribute vec3 aPosition;
attribute vec2 aTexCoord;

varying vec2 vTexCoord;

// We always must do at least one thing in the vertex shader:
// tell the pixel where on the screen it lives:

void main() {
  // copy the texcoords
  vTexCoord = aTexCoord;

  // copy the position data into a vec4, using 1.0 as the w component
  vec4 positionVec4 = vec4(aPosition, 1.0);
  positionVec4.xy = positionVec4.xy * 2.0 - 1.0;

  // Send the vertex information on to the fragment shader
  // this is done automatically, as long as you put it into the built in shader function “gl_Position”
  gl_Position = positionVec4;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long story short: the texture coordinates for a rectangle or a plane drawn with p5.js are (0, 0) in the bottom left, and (1, 1) in the top right, where as the coordinate system for sampling values from a texture are (0, 0) in the *top* left and (1, 1) in the *bottom* right. You can verify this by commenting out your color sampling code in your fragment shader and using the following:

```
float val = (uv.x + uv.y) / 2.0;
gl_FragColor = vec4(val, val, val, 1.0);
```

As you can see by the resulting image:

[image]

The value `(0 + 0) / 2` results in black in the lower left, and `(1 + 1) / 2` results in white in the upper right.

So, to sample the correct portion of the texture you just need to flip the `y` component of the `uv` vector:

```
texture2D(u_texture, vec2(uv.x, 1.0 - uv.y));
```

```js
const sketch = (p5) => {
  const D = 200;
  let initialTexture;

  p5.preload = () => {
    // This doesn't actually need to go in preload
    // Create the initial image
    initialTexture = p5.createImage(D, D);
    initialTexture.loadPixels();
    for (let i = 0; i < initialTexture.width; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < initialTexture.height; j++) {
        // draw a big checkerboard
        const alive = (p5.round(i / 10) + p5.round(j / 10)) % 2 == 0;

        const color = alive ? p5.color('white') : p5.color(150, p5.map(j, 0, D, 50, 200), p5.map(i, 0, D, 50, 200));
        initialTexture.set(i, j, color);
      }
    }
    initialTexture.updatePixels();
  };

  p5.setup = () => {
    const canvas = p5.createCanvas(D, D, p5.WEBGL);

    // Create the buffer the shader will draw on
    graphics = p5.createGraphics(D, D, p5.WEBGL);
    // Initialize the shader
    shader = graphics.createShader(vert, frag);

    graphics.shader(shader);

    /*
     * Initial step to setup the initial texture
     */
    // Used to normalize the frag coordinates
    shader.setUniform('u_resolution', [p5.width, p5.height]);
    // First state of the simulation
    shader.setUniform('u_texture', initialTexture);
    graphics.rect(0, 0, p5.width, p5.height);

    // Call the shader each time interval
    setInterval(updateSimulation, 100);
  };

  const updateSimulation = () => {
    // Use the previous state as a texture
    shader.setUniform('u_texture', graphics);
    graphics.rect(0, 0, p5.width, p5.height);
  };

  p5.draw = () => {
    p5.background(0);
    // Use the buffer on the canvas
    p5.texture(graphics);
    p5.rect(-p5.width / 2, -p5.height / 2, p5.width, p5.height);
  };

  const frag = `
precision highp float;

uniform vec2 u_resolution;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;

// grab texcoords from vert shader
varying vec2 vTexCoord;
varying vec2 vPos;

void main() {
    // Get the texture coordinate from the vertex shader
    vec2 uv = vTexCoord;

    gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture, vec2(uv.x, 1.0 - uv.y));

    //// For debugging uv coordinate orientation
    // float val = (uv.x + uv.y) / 2.0;
    // gl_FragColor = vec4(val, val, val, 1.0);
}
`;

  const vert = `
/*
 * vert file and comments from adam ferriss https://github.com/aferriss/p5jsShaderExamples with additional comments from Louise Lessel
*/ 

precision highp float;

// This “vec3 aPosition” is a built in shader functionality. You must keep that naming.
// It automatically gets the position of every vertex on your canvas
attribute vec3 aPosition;
attribute vec2 aTexCoord;

varying vec2 vTexCoord;

// We always must do at least one thing in the vertex shader:
// tell the pixel where on the screen it lives:

void main() {
  // copy the texcoords
  vTexCoord = aTexCoord;

  // copy the position data into a vec4, using 1.0 as the w component
  vec4 positionVec4 = vec4(aPosition, 1.0);
  // This maps positions 0..1 to -1..1
  positionVec4.xy = positionVec4.xy * 2.0 - 1.0;

  // Send the vertex information on to the fragment shader
  // this is done automatically, as long as you put it into the built in shader function “gl_Position”
  gl_Position = positionVec4;
}`;
};

new p5(sketch);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.3.1/lib/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ah thanks! I didn't know that the coordinates were inverted like this that's good to know

Comment: No problem. I was surprised that this was the case myself, so I learned something too!

Comment: Also, if you're interested in a reference example of a Game of Life shader: https://openprocessing.org/sketch/1107781  
It's a bit different from your approach because I use vertex coordinates to map to squares in the GOL grid instead of texture coordinates (I retrospect I like your approach better, but at the time I think I probably hit this flipped y-axis issue and just switched to the vertex coords).

Comment: That's super interesting I'll definitely get some inspiration from your code! Thank you very much for sharing.